# Absolute positioning with scrolling navbar

Tags: css, positioning, nav, absolute

Need a bit of help, couldn't find this specific problem on here. I've got an absolute positioned navbar at the bottom of my webpage, the content of the page being max 1000px width but so that the navbar can stretch with the browser (though when browser is resized to less than 1000px width the navbar sits at a fixed width).

Here's an example:
http://trademarkjunkie.com/absolute

Everything is working fine, but if you resize the browser horizontally to less than 1000px and scroll left and right, the content scrolls (as it should), but the navbar content is fixed. I want this to scroll with the content, but behave exactly as it is doing in all other instance.

Any thoughts? The missing image in the centre at the bottom is a scroll-top bottom to jump up the page so ignore that. You can grab the CSS here:
http://trademarkjunkie.com/absolute/style.css

Any help would be appreciated, cheers.

EDIT - I've updated the link and centred the text in a div with auto horizontal margins (and changed the position in css from fixed to absolute). As you scroll down, the bar stays in the original position on the browser, and doesn't remain bottom aligned. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

> but the navbar content is fixed.  I want this to scroll with the content, but behave exactly as it is doing in all other instance.

The bottom navbar is positioned as "fixed", hence it doesn't scroll with your content. If you want to scroll, try giving your class "bottom-nav" a position of "absolute" instead of "fixed".

Think this should answer your question if I interpreted it correctly..

Comment: I tried that, but it's doing a very strange thing. I've updated the link and centred the text in a div with auto horizontal margins so you can see:

http://trademarkjunkie.com/absolute

As you scroll down, the bar stays in the original position on the browser, and doesn't remain bottom aligned. Any thoughts?

Comment: Classic "Sticky footer" problem. You want it to have a fixed position on vertical scroll and absolute positioning on horizontal scroll, correct?

[Check out this link](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)

I'll provide you with a code sample tonight.

Comment: Applied the "Sticky Footer" to your HTML/CSS. Good luck!
[Sticky Footer](http://cdpn.io/wGmBK)
*also: try and use classes more instead of ID's.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the help. However that link you sent with the sticky footer implemented into my page, it doesn't seem to work. I need a footer stuck to the bottom of the browser, not to the bottom of the page. It should stretch to full browser width when browser is wider than 1000px, and when under 1000px should stay at that fixed width, the the ability to scroll horizontally with the other content on the page, but should also stay at the bottom of the browser when scrolling vertically.